How to keep the centerline on upwind / departure leg?
I'm a student pilot training with C172. The area usually do not have strong winds, but when there's ~5kts crosswind component, it's difficult for me to keep the runway centerline after taking off.
I saw an advice to see a reference point in distance like a specific point of clouds and trying to follow it, but I'm still drifting towards downwind. What references do you use to keep the centerline in a departure leg / upwind?

This is a very common problem with student pilots, and to some  extent comes (like most things) with practice and experience. That said there are some visual guides you can use - sounds like you've been told about them, and some more analytical planned things you can use.
What you could do is basically the same as when you're on final; namely crab slightly into the wind. To calculate the amount you can use the typical "Max Drift" calculation (based on a simple rule of thumb 1:60 rule) and then estimate based on the crosswind component.
For example:

You're taking off from runway 26, and your TAS is 80Kts. The wind is 290/12

$ \text{Max Drift} = \frac {60} {80} \times 12 = 9 $
Then calculate the wind correction by a simple estimate based on crosswind component

15 degrees off = apply quarter
30 degrees off = apply half
45 degrees off = apply three quarters
60 degrees or more = apply all

So in this example your wind is 30 degrees off your course, so apply half the max drift, so you should adjust your heading by 5 degrees (half of 9).
On take off, adjust your heading by 5 degrees into wind to stay on the extended centreline. Of course, on the downwind leg you can just adjust the same amount the opposite direction.
However, don't overthink this - nobody is going to worry too much about a student pilot drifting slightly from the centreline. It's more important to concentrate on your speed and situational awareness in the pattern than being too exact. Your instructor will get you to "tighten" up your accuracy as and when they feel you've nailed the other bits.

@DJClayworth yep of course I did... thanks for catching that.

Problem with this method is that wind at 100ft will be different from that found in metar. 200 even more so and it just keeps getting worse. It'll get you off the ground good enough for sure, but adhering to a numeric value all the way to pattern altitude most likely will not keep one aligned.

@Jpe61 of course you're right, and trying to be too exact about this will just lead to more problems. It's more about feeling what's happening which as I said comes with experience. This method, if using the winds at ground level might give you a good start for the first 100ft or so. ie/ if you know you need to adjust heading 5 degrees left you do so soon after you lift, it might make it a bit easier for you.

You have to establish a crab angle appropriate to the cross wind, same as you establish a crab angle while flying a cross country track with a wind from the side, or a crab angle on final.
So you take off and fly runway heading and immediately find yourself drifting left. Make a coordinated turn to the right, say 5 degrees heading change, then hold that heading. If you're still drifting, increase to 10 degrees, and so on.
Shortly you'll learn to anticipate the ballpark crab angle you need, and make a coordinated turn to the required heading as soon as you are airborne. So light crosswind, turn 5 degrees right, strong crosswind, 10 degrees right. Hold the heading, assess, and adjust as required.
Once you've found how much crab angle to use and have set a heading, look out to find a landmark to use as a reference so you can maintain the heading while keeping your head outside.

The root cause of the drifting is that winds are generally higher as one climbs away from the ground.  This is known as a wind gradient, and it can also affect your glide path on approach to landing.
Expect more control inputs to correct for wind drift as you climb.
As with anything involved with piloting, it is best to be ahead of the issue, rather than correcting after drifting downwind.
Expect your distant reference point to move left or right in the wind shield as you add more control inputs to compensate for the wind drift, and try to fly upwind of it at first.
Practice will make perfect, and it will be helpful to look at a map and pick out intermediate ground points along your flight path to help hold course, such as roads, buildings, parks, etc.
In the future, for longer trips, these reference points may be replaced by radio beacons, but visual navigation will do for now.

The fundamental here is to learn to keep runway centerline during takeoff roll in crosswind conditions. Avoid pumping the rudder but aim to find a constant pressure on the pedal which keeps you on the centerline. Also, if I remember correctly the crosswind procedure for C172 calls for deflecting the ailerons (yoke) towards the wind. The yoke shall be returned gradually to center during takeoff roll so that ailerons are centered at the time of liftoff.
During the rotation, gently release pressure on the pedals and center them. When performed optimally, the yoke and pedals are centered when the main landing gear lifts up and the track of the aircraft is at that moment still along the centerline of the runway.
Once airborne, with correct track and lateral flight controls centered, the aerodynamics will take care of the rest. As the mass of the aircraft is already going to the right direction, the vertical stabilizer will turn the aircraft nose towards the wind to balance the airflow, which is not from straight ahead due to crosswind. Do not prevent this change of few degrees in yaw, as it will automatically put the aircraft on the correct heading to compensate the wind. If any roll is induced, level the wings with ailerons.
Then take a fixed position along the intended flight path and gently make small corrections in the heading with ailerons to keep the desired track as the wind changes as you climb.
